# Embed Vaadin 7 Application on another domain/site (Cross-Site)

Tags: vaadin, cross-site

I'm evaluating Vaadin for an internal web application and one requirement I have is to embed the web application (hosted on mydomain:8080) into another site (hosted on mydomain:80).

For Vaadin 6, the [XS add-on](http://vaadin.com/directory#addon/vaadin-xs) let me do this with ease however for Vaadin 7 the only way I can do cross-site embedding is with an IFRAME (which is not a good option for me).

Has anyone been able to embed a Vaadin 7 web application on another domain/port?  If so how?

NOTE;
- I control the web servers hosting mydomain:8080 (Tomcat 7.0.51) and mydomain:80 (Apache httpd 2.2) so I can change the config if it helps.
- I tried CORS on the Tomcat side.  It didn't help.
- I tried just using Vaadin-XS with Vaadin 7.  It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do 2 things:

1.- Enable CORS in your server side, either using a [Filter](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/Ajax#CORS_%28Cross_Origin_Resource_Sharing%29) or [customising](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/4874540/4874539) your vaadin servlet.

2.- Change the bootstrap script so as you set these parameters:

```
"serviceUrl": "http://mydomain:8080",
"browserDetailsUrl": "http://mydomain:8080",
```